# How to avoid `&` conflict when using `\begin{align}` in a tabular cell?

Tags: align, tables, ampersand

## Minimal CODE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage
{%
    array,
    calc,
    amsmath,
    longtable,
    varwidth%
}

\newsavebox\TBox
\newcolumntype{B}[1]
{%
    @{}%
    >{\begin{lrbox}{\TBox}\varwidth{\linewidth}}%
    m{#1\linewidth-1.5\arrayrulewidth}%
    <{%
            \endvarwidth\end{lrbox}\fboxrule=0pt%
            \fboxsep=15pt\fbox{\usebox\TBox}%
     }%
    @{}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*2{B{0.5}|}}\hline
\begin{align}
a &= b
\end{align} 
& c \tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

**How to avoid `&` conflict when using `\begin{align}` in a tabular cell?**

Comment: Put the environment into braces `{...}`. However there will be a problem with the equationnumber. A number makes no real sense to me. Do you really need it?

Comment: @Herbert, my real scenario is to create INPUT-OUTPUT table. Input cell contains the LaTeX code and the OUTPUT cell contains the corresponding output. When I want to show `\begin{align}`, the output should provide the proper output. :-)

Comment: If you want to create INPUT-OUTPUT table, maybe you should just use `minipage` instead of `tabular`.

Comment: the align environment is buggy when you want to cut off the surrounding white space, see page 74 in `http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf`. Use only the m column type _without_ a parbox or minipage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `\parbox` or `minipage` within the cell, the `&` works as expected and you would get also the equation number. For example:

```
\begin{longtable}{|*2{B{0.5}|}}\hline
\parbox{.5\linewidth}{%
  \begin{align}
    a &= b
  \end{align}} 
  & c \tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}
```

[image: longtable with align in cell]

Comment: thanks for answering. Both Herbert's and your solutions work.